# Modifying existing firefox extension doesn't work because of signatures

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, selenium-firefoxdriver, metamask

I've got the extension [Metamask](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ether-metamask/) which pops up notification and asks me to click the button `Unlock` to access a website. I'm trying to automate it by adding a javascript code to click on the button automatically, but when I made the changes to .xpi file and saved it, the extension simply disappeared probably because the signature now couldn't verify the extension. The error it shows is
`MetaMask could not be verified for use in Firefox and has been disabled.` The old solution like toggling `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false no more works after Firefox 44.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve the same?

Comment: It's possible to load an extension from a file - no sig check, but the ext will only be available until you close FF. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension).

Answer (score 1):

You can not use unsigned extension on release version of Firefox, but you can on Nightly or Developer edition of the Firefox.

[Download and test future releases of Firefox for desktop, Android and iOS.](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/)